# 'Jenkins' user is not created on OS X install

Tags: xcode, macos, jenkins

When reading about Jenkins installation, many guides talk about that the installer created a user called 'Jenkins' on OS X. This user seems to be important for certain tasks.
However, installing Jenkins 2.32 using homebrew does not install this user here. Why is that - am I missing something?

Background: I want to run CI for iOS together with a Gitlab server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jenkins installed via Homebrew is kind of a mess - and I say this because it isn't terribly obvious in the log output where/who gets permissions.

Jenkins DOES NOT create a jenkins user on Mac OS (nor should it ever, imo).

By default, the user that was actively using `brew install jenkins` is the one who will get the default permissions. There should be a `/.jenkins` folder within that users home folder (ex: `/Users/<your_user>/.jenkins`)

The problem is that when `brew` finishes running, some files that should get symlinked to the active user *don't* - so you might create a job using rvm/ruby for example, and get errors that bundler can't write to the system ruby.

Try this in terminal/iTerm:

> sudo chown `whoami` /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.jenkins.plist

also `whoami` should be surrounded by ticks `

I tend to just do these commands after a `brew install jenkins`

`ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/jenkins/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents`

Symlink the Jenkins plist files to /Library/LaunchAgents

`sudo cp -fv /usr/local/opt/jenkins/*.plist /Library/LaunchDaemons`

Copy plist files to /Library/LaunchDaemons

`sudo chown`whoami`/Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.jenkins.plist`

Give sudo ownership of the plist file listed to the user outright

---

This part isn't necessary...

`launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.jenkins.plist`

`launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.jenkins.plist`

Here's something to refer to:

http://flummox-engineering.blogspot.com/2016/01/installing-jenkins-os-x-homebrew.html