# Connect to Bitbucket repo over SSH after install on macOS view homebrew

Tags: git, macos, jenkins, ssh, bitbucket

I'm having a frustrating time getting this set up. Currently my Bitbucket account is having [a problem connecting over HTTPS](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/Getting-quot-Too-many-invalid-password-attempts-quot-error/qaq-p/615807) and so I'm trying to connect to my repo using SSH but have encountered problems.

This is my first time using Jenkins so bear with me. I installed Jenkins using *homebrew* which was very simple.

1. I let Jenkins install the recommended plugins which included git and ssh plugins and created a password for the admin user.
2. I generated a new SSH key on my machine using the method described [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-an-ssh-key-728138079.html), added it as an Access Key to my Bitbucket repo, and confirmed that it worked by cloning from the terminal.
3. I added the SSH keys to Jenkins and it picked up the public key from my `~/.ssh` folder
4. I created a new Freestyle project in Jenkins and added new git repository by supplying the `git@bitbucket.org:myrepo.git` URL.
5. I instructed it to use my SSH key from the dropdown as credentials.

My efforts were rewarded with this error:

> Failed to connect to repository : Command "git ls-remote -h
>   git@bitbucket.org:myrepo.git HEAD" returned status
>   code 128: stdout:  stderr: Permission denied (publickey).  fatal:
>   Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

#### Some Possible Leads

I've heard it said that Jenkins creates a new user on your machine and that the reason the SSH key might not work is because the jenkins user does not have access to it. I have not found any evidence of it creating a user and have even heard that [it does not create a user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42636058/jenkins-user-is-not-created-on-os-x-install), maybe this was old behaviour.

I've tried switching to this Jenkins users [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41572296/415219) but to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit:** One additional thing I've heard (somewhere) is that it might work better if your SSH keys were created without a passphrase. Sounds like it would be less secure in that case so I'm not sure if I should try that.

Comment: what user account did you generate the key for, and is the Jenkins slave using the same user? There should be a drop down under the clone url in jenkins to pick the correct user.

Comment: I used the same user account that I used to install Jenkins. I'm currently logged into Jenkins using the default admin account. In the credentials dropdown under the repo URL I see my own name as the only choice. Is there a way to tell what user the "Jenkins slave" corresponds to?

Comment: I am just trying to understand your environment. Is your machine a jenkins slave?

Comment: It's just a Mac Mini on which I'm trying to install Jenkins and Fastlane to automate my iOS builds whenever I commit to Bitbucket. It's not a dev machine or anything.

Comment: Can you try adding your private key to jenkins credentials? Jenkins > Credentials > System > Global credentials > select your user, select update, paste in private key

Comment: Yeah I added the credentials that way. That's how Jenkins recognizes them in the dropdown when I try to add the repo to the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I just found out what was going on.

Even though I added my SSH key to Jenkins and it was accessible via the Credentials dropdown in the Source Code Management section of my project the `ssh-agent` on my machine (which Jenkins uses) didn't know about my keys and I needed to add them.

> **Solution:**
>
> On the machine where Jenkins is installed:
>
> 1. Open up a terminal
> 2. Enter: `ssh-add -l`
> 3. If you don't see your keys listed (mine said "The agent has no identities.") then you'll need to add them.    Enter: `ssh-add <path-to-key>` (the default path is usually something like
>      `~/.ssh/id_rsa`)
> 4. If you have a passphrase for your key you'll need to enter it here.
> 5. Now go back to your Jenkins project, add your repo URL, then select your credentials and it should work

Hope that helps someone avoid wasting their time like I did.