# Fastlane working on terminal not on Jenkins

Tags: swift, jenkins, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, fastlane

I am able to configure Fastlane locally and working well with terminal, but when I am trying to run it with Jenkins(I have configured Jenkins locally on my macbook) it is failing every-time(i have installed ruby 2.5.0 again).
Any help on the same would be highly appreciated.

I am attaching SS for your reference.

[image]

Comment: Did you try brew doctor?

Comment: yes. I already tried .

Comment: How did you install jenkins? With brew?

Comment: Have you checked this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42636058/jenkins-user-is-not-created-on-os-x-install

Comment: @grizzthedj sorry for late reply yes using brew.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins run its build scripts using specified user 'jenkins'. You might want to check if 'jenkins' user had installed requires dependencies to run `fastlane`, for e.g `ruby` ...

Answer (score 0):

Have you set up your `PATH` in Jenkins? In the configuration of your node, in the environment variables section, you'll want to include `/usr/local/bin/` with Jenkins's `PATH` by entering `/usr/local/bin/:$PATH`.

Comment: This is not working.  I tried with /bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin and worked